# How to log PHP file run with jQuery AJAX in browser console?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, data-processing

I have a PHP file that does data processing. It's run by `$.ajax()`, sometimes on big files that take a long time to process. I need to log some info about the ongoing process in the browser console that is displayed *on the go*, not just when the PHP file has finished running.

From the research I did, I get that there are two difficulties:

1. Getting PHP to spit out something before it's done
2. Getting jQuery/JS to display it on the go

To address #1, I've tried:

```
echo "started"."<br>";

foreach (array("done this", "done that","had a coffee","burp") as $msg) {
    sleep(3);
    echo $msg."<br>";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

`flush(); ob_flush();` is supposed to do the job, although as you can test [here](http://constances-web-dev.vjf.inserm.fr/constances-web/ajax-test.php) it does not strictly display ever 3s as it's expected to. Any suggestion to get it to display as expected?

As for how to address #2, I have explored a solution involving `XMLHttpRequest`, but I'm not familiar with the subject so not sure neither what to look for nor if it's the right direction...

Here is the test code of what I'm trying to get to run:

```js
$("#run").click(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://constances-web-dev.vjf.inserm.fr/constances-web/ajax-test.php",
    xhr: function() {
      // get the native XmlHttpRequest object
      var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
        console.log(e)
      });
      // set the onprogress event handler
      //xhr.onprogress = function(evt){ console.log(evt.target.response) } ;
      // set the onload event handler
      return xhr;
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
      console.log("Erreur: " + msg);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="run">go</button>
```

*Subsidiary question:* Is there an (easy) way to go around the cross-origin restriction in order to get an AJAX example to work in a SO snippet?

Comment: For your subsidiary question, the answer unfortunately is **no**. [Here](http://stacksnippets.net/) is the SO explanation.

Comment: hey @freginold thanks so much for your help ! wondering why a snipet is recommanded since the code involves ajax that can not be run ?

Comment: @freginold also thanks for +1 which as far as i understood got me the 5 reputation I needed to reach 50. I'm a big girl now, can comment !!! tadaa!

Comment: You can still see if any console messages or errors are generated, depending on the example, and it provides a better way to organize the code than just a code block.

Comment: ok got that , thks

Comment: @freginold actually, I don't get the same origin thing... what I get from [this](http://http://stacksnippets.net/) is that snippets are not run _here_ to prevent evil people to mess up with _this_ site. Snippet code being run on another domain the same origin constrains protects this site. My question is about having a 3rd origin for ajax run php files, in other words whether _under certains condition_ , the same origin constrain can be by passed

Comment: That would probably be a good question to ask on [the Meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: bllamoo [Same-origin policy and php file ajax run from other domain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357108/same-origin-policy-and-php-file-ajax-run-from-other-domain)

Comment: @freginold if someone can tell me why [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357108/same-origin-policy-and-php-file-ajax-run-from-other-domain) got down tagged, I'd be very interested !!!

Comment: Hard to say...  that's a lot of downvotes very quickly. Usually questions are downvoted because they show no effort by the asker, they are hard to understand, or they are not useful to the site and to future readers. My guess would be yours got downvoted for the last reason, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

as a work around I've added a log to file to my write2log function

```
static function log2File($string, $logFileName) {
        if (substr($string,0,1 ) == "\n")
            exec("echo '".date('Y-m-d_H:i:s')." ".addslashes(substr($string,1))."' >> ".$logFileName,$output,$status);
        else
            exec("echo -n ".addslashes($string)."' >> ".$logFileName,$output,$status);
    }
```

I can then `tail -f` the log to watch how things are going

but this takes ssh access to the server so
i'd still be interested in figuring out how to log to console