# Canceled Bootstrap modal still triggers canceled action when reopened (with class)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

The following code displays a list of document types with a button for each of them that allows to upload a document and use the document type as a variable (for different puposes).

The `modal-addDoc` class on each button triggers the opening of a modal with a form inside in order to collect information that need to be recorded with the file.

---

### The problem:

when the button for a certain doc type is clicked and the modal is then canceled (user opened the wrong type of doc) and another button is then clicked, and after that the "enregistrer" button in the modal is clicked, actions for both the canceled type and the latest type are triggered. For demonstration purposes, in the following snippet the action is just an alert.

*Example:*

- click on green button in CRANAP line
- click "annuler" (=cancel)
- click on green button in CRHOSP line
- click "enregistrer"

You will get 2 alerts: one for CRANAP and then one for CRHOSP.

I need to understand why the first alert is still triggered (because I have more code with the same structure and problem).

Any ideas are welcome!

```js
$('.modal-addDoc').click(function() {
    var uidTypeDoc = $(this).attr('data-uidTypeDoc');
    var uidQuest = $(this).attr('data-uidQuest');
    $("[id^=addDoc]").attr("id","addDoc-"+uidQuest+"-"+uidTypeDoc);
    $('#modal-addDoc').modal();
    $("#uidTypeDoc").text(" de type "+uidTypeDoc);
    var addDocId = "addDoc-"+uidQuest+"-"+uidTypeDoc;
    console.log(addDocId);
    $("#"+addDocId).click(function() {
        alert(addDocId)
    })
});
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Dossier de l'enquête n°2038 - PRIMEV'R</title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_dataTools/css/dataTools.css">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_dataTools/css/with-materialadmin.css">
 
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_dataTools/css/primevr.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_assets/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<style> button {height:30px}</style></head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered table-stripped no-margin">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="7">Questionnaire n° 2038_1 : <em class="text-default-light"><small>aucune pathologie confirmée</small></em></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CRANAP" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CRANAP">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR d'anatomopathologie (ponction, biopsie, myélogramme)</strong> <span>(CRANAP)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CRHOSP" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CRHOSP">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR d'hospitalisation</strong> <span>(CRHOSP)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CROAPP" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CROAPP">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR d'opération, analyse pathologique de la pièce opératoire</strong> <span>(CROAPP)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CRRCPL" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CRRCPL">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR de réunion de concertation pluridisciplinaire (RCP)</strong> <span>(CRRCPL)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document DOMATU" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_DOMATU">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>Dosages de marqueurs tumoraux (ex. PSA)</strong> <span>(DOMATU)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                            <th width="1%"></th>
                            <th>Date du document</th>
                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Date d'ajout</th>
                            <th>Utilisateur</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th width="1%"></th>
                        </tr>
                                      
                                </tbody>
        </table>

<div id="modal-addDoc" class="modal animated fadeInUp" data-easein="fadeInUp" data-easeout="fadeOutUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>Charger un document <span id="uidTypeDoc"></span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form id="form-addDoc" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <input name="uidEnq" value="2038" type="hidden">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label><strong>Choisir le document</strong>
                                <input required="" name="document" type="file">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 input-group date">
                            <div class="input-group-content">
                                <label><strong>Date du document</strong>
                                    <input required="" class="form-control" name="dateDoc" placeholder="(J)J/(M)M/(AA)AA" type="text">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row margin-top margin-left">
                        <label style="width:90%"><strong>Description</strong>
                            <textarea name="descr" rows="5" class="col-sm-12"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <progress id="progress" style="display:none;"></progress>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addDoc">Enregistrer</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Annuler</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like you're just hiding the modal, rather than removing it.

Comment: hey @freginold thks for the input. what do you mean "removing it" ? I can not delete the html element since it can still be needed if another download button is clicked ...?-|

Comment: If you can't delete the HTML element that houses the modal, maybe you could clear it out before adding the new modal in. The way it is right now, you're hiding the first (canceled) modal, but the functionality remains.

Comment: what would "clear it out" then be ? I tried to reset the form, but as the snippet shows because the form is not used, it is not a problem with the form

Comment: Full disclosure, I contribute to this project, but: you might find something like [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) (specifically, the custom dialog) useful - the modals are (by default) recreated each time you show the dialog, so you don't run into the problem of stale data.

Comment: what do you mean by " but the functionality remains" ? I thought the modal being just one html element could only be associated with one action, especially after I added a specific id (including doc type) to the "enregistrer" button. How can a click to a specific id trigger two actions ??? this looks like witchery to me !

Comment: @v2belleville Let me take a closer look at it, and I'll try to give a better explanation...

Comment: @freginold great thks !

Comment: @ Tieson T thks for the suggestion but I 've simplified the code to the core problem, in real life need to do pretty complex stuff (different ajax call) with the modal, not sure Bootbox does that, also, I'd very much prefer to understand this behavior than rewrite quite a bit of code to include the tool ... ;)

Comment: @v2belleville See my answer below for an explanation and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting multiple `alert` actions when that happens is because the click handler from the prior selected option is not being removed. So each time an option is selected, a new click handler is being added, but the old one is not being removed:

```
$("#"+addDocId).click(function() {
    alert(addDocId)
})
```

All you have to do is insert an `.off()` statement before adding the click handler, to remove any prior handlers/listeners.  See this example, which only displays an `alert` for the currently-selected option:

```js
$('.modal-addDoc').click(function() {
    var uidTypeDoc = $(this).attr('data-uidTypeDoc');
    var uidQuest = $(this).attr('data-uidQuest');
    $("[id^=addDoc]").attr("id","addDoc-"+uidQuest+"-"+uidTypeDoc);
    $('#modal-addDoc').modal();
    $("#uidTypeDoc").text(" de type "+uidTypeDoc);
    var addDocId = "addDoc-"+uidQuest+"-"+uidTypeDoc;
    console.log(addDocId);
    $("#"+addDocId).off();      // remove any previously-added listeners
    $("#"+addDocId).click(function() {
        alert(addDocId);
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Dossier de l'enquête n°2038 - PRIMEV'R</title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_dataTools/css/dataTools.css">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_dataTools/css/with-materialadmin.css">
 
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_dataTools/css/primevr.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_assets/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://primevr-preprod.constances.fr/_assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<style> button {height:30px}</style></head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered table-stripped no-margin">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="7">Questionnaire n° 2038_1 : <em class="text-default-light"><small>aucune pathologie confirmée</small></em></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CRANAP" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CRANAP">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR d'anatomopathologie (ponction, biopsie, myélogramme)</strong> <span>(CRANAP)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CRHOSP" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CRHOSP">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR d'hospitalisation</strong> <span>(CRHOSP)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CROAPP" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CROAPP">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR d'opération, analyse pathologique de la pièce opératoire</strong> <span>(CROAPP)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document CRRCPL" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_CRRCPL">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>CR de réunion de concertation pluridisciplinaire (RCP)</strong> <span>(CRRCPL)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs modal-addDoc" title="Ajouter un document DOMATU" data-uidquest="2038_1" data-uidtypedoc="CA_DOMATU">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="style-default" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            <strong>Dosages de marqueurs tumoraux (ex. PSA)</strong> <span>(DOMATU)</span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="style-default align-right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                            <th width="1%"></th>
                            <th>Date du document</th>
                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Date d'ajout</th>
                            <th>Utilisateur</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th width="1%"></th>
                        </tr>
                                      
                                </tbody>
        </table>

<div id="modal-addDoc" class="modal animated fadeInUp" data-easein="fadeInUp" data-easeout="fadeOutUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>Charger un document <span id="uidTypeDoc"></span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form id="form-addDoc" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <input name="uidEnq" value="2038" type="hidden">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label><strong>Choisir le document</strong>
                                <input required="" name="document" type="file">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 input-group date">
                            <div class="input-group-content">
                                <label><strong>Date du document</strong>
                                    <input required="" class="form-control" name="dateDoc" placeholder="(J)J/(M)M/(AA)AA" type="text">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row margin-top margin-left">
                        <label style="width:90%"><strong>Description</strong>
                            <textarea name="descr" rows="5" class="col-sm-12"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <progress id="progress" style="display:none;"></progress>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addDoc">Enregistrer</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Annuler</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: excellent ! it does work !!! why it does is absolutely mysterious though : at the time $("#"+addDocId).off(); is run, addDocId has the value of the new doc type, who can it remove a listener on the previous doctype ???

Comment: It seems that even though you're changing the ID, it's the same button, so the click handler from before is carried over.

Comment: yes, you're probably right since this would also explain the weird behaviour i was struggling with. not very logical thought, probably something for jquery people to arrange ... thks again for your input

Comment: hey @freginold , I *know* I should not be doing this, but I'm absolutely stucked with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863567/how-to-log-php-file-run-with-jquery-ajax-in-browser-console have no clue in which direction I could still be looking, also I do not understand why it only got 23 viewing. I'd totally understand if you simply ignore this msg, but any clue on how to get people to read it, what to look into to figure a solution out, or anything that could help would be very very much welcomed !

Comment: I made a few changes that should help it get more views; added the 'php' tag, changed the formatting, and made your code into a snippet. Hopefully someone with an idea will take a look.